# How to make a Recycler View scroll slow and smooth when the user takes hands off the screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, user-experience

This is how the current implementation when I scroll fast.

[image]

With in second the whole items in the recycler view are showed till the end.. What I am trying to achieve is something like the one shown below (live demo: recycler views in play store),

[image]

even if we scroll fast it shows 1 or 2 items so it feels natural. How can I make the recycler view behave this way?

The code:

Adapter

```
class CustomAdapter(private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_design, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview)
        val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
val recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
val data = ArrayList<ItemsViewModel>()
val adapter = CustomAdapter(data)
recyclerview.adapter = adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

When a `RecyclerView` is scrolled horizontally, the `scrollHorizontallyBy()` is called several times with dx values that can make the scrolling behave smooth and real according to the fling (push) value of the finger.

The same for vertical `RecyclerView`, `scrollVerticallyBy()` gets called with different dy values.

So, you can manipulate this `dx` value to have the desired behavior; in your case you need to get smaller values of `dx`.

You'd think of a fixed `dx` value, but that won't be that natural; instead you can divide it by a fixed amount to scale down the same dx values.

Here I'm using an arbitrary value that you can manipulate it as you need.

So, what you need is to use a custom `LinearLayoutManager` & override  `scrollHorizontallyBy()` as you use a horizontal recyclerView:

```
class MyLinearLayoutManager(context: Context?, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) :
    LinearLayoutManager(context, orientation, reverseLayout) {

    override fun scrollHorizontallyBy(
        dx: Int,
        recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?,
        state: RecyclerView.State?
    ): Int {
        var newDx = (dx / 1.2).toInt() // 1.2 is an arbitrary value 
        if (newDx == 0 && dx != 0) { // To have no 0 values (Optionally)
            newDx = 1
        }
        
        return super.scrollHorizontallyBy(newDx, recycler, state)
    }

}
```